# Largest eigenvalue of sums of non Hermetican matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

As it is already known from Alfred Horn's [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1103036720) "Eigenvalues of sums of Hermetian matrices" that: if $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian matrices, and the eigenvalues of these matrices are respectively $\lambda_1,\lambda_2....\lambda_N$ and  $\mu_1,\mu_2....\mu_N$. Where,

$\lambda_1>\lambda_2>...>\lambda_N$ and $\mu_1>\mu_2>...>\mu_N$.

If $M=A+B$, and $\nu_1,\nu_2....\nu_N$ are the eigenvalues of $M$ then

first condition from Horn's paper,

$\sum_{i=1}^N\nu_i$=$\sum_{i=1}^N\lambda_i+\sum_{i=1}^N\mu_i$

then others for $i=1..r$. However, my question is on the largest one, ${\lambda_1, \mu_1 and~\nu_1}$, which shows the following condition,

$\nu_1\leq\lambda_1+\mu_1$

Now, the question is, What will happen to the above largest eigenvalue condition if $A$ and $B$ are non-hermitian matrices which has complex conjugate eigenvalues? should it be:

$|\nu_1|\leq|\lambda_1|+|\mu_1|$ or $|\nu_1|\leq|\lambda_1+\mu_1|$

Many thanks, sincerely yours.